# How to get wireless LAN working with Raspberry pi - network connection reset by peer

Tags: raspbian, networking, usb, wireless, ssh

I don't have any monitor. I have installed Raspbian in RPi. I have remotely accessed Raspberry pi through my PC via SSH through ethernet cable. All I want to do is to access wifi through edup EP-N8531 wifi adapter(802.11n USB Wireless verified peripheral). Whenever I connect wifi dongle to Raspberry pi it was showing:

> network connection reset by peer .

I am running XMing server ([here](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/)) in my PC.
Is operating RPi via SSH creating problem, If I were to install settings via SSH do I have to follow different technique, if anyone knows step by step procedure to install wifi driver in Raspberry pi  pease help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply more information. I suggest you hook up the Pi to a screen (via the HDMI or RCA output).

I can think of two things happening in your setup:

1. The Pi reboots when you connect the WiFi dongle. This may be due to an insufficient power supply or some faulty driver (I assume the former).
2. The Ethernet connection gets disabled when the WiFi dongle is attached and activated. However, I don't think this is the case with Raspbian.

So for further help, you may need to supply the following information:

- What does the Pi do after you attach the dongle? Hook it up to a screen to find out!
- Take a look at the kernel log with `tail -f /var/log/messages` to see if anything useful is logged.
- Check your network setup with `ifconfig` before and after you attach the dongle.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that deleting dhcpcd.conf will resolve the problem.I tried many of methods that mentioned in threads but didn't work.

code:

```
cd /etc           
sudo rm dhcpcd.conf
```

Try this